# Upgrade 18.04 to 20

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. `do-release-upgrade` terminates with this error message: https://pastebin.com/PzZf408W

I did a lot of research, also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278878/18-04-%E2%86%92-20-04-upgrade-fails-eunable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken) old thread, but it doesn't solve my problem. I already disabled all third party repos.
I couldn't find anything in the [main.log](https://pastebin.com/dMLeqsf3) and I'm not sure what to look for in the [apt.log](https://pastebin.com/5s6uzkv4). The first half of the packages seem to go no problem, the second half shows broken packages but also mentions "considering XXX as a solution".

So I really have no idea any more what to do.

```
Linux pc-f-linux 4.18.8-041808-generic #201809150431 SMP Sat Sep 15 08:33:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If you need more information let me know!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked was to replace `bionic` with `focal` in the sources and then run `apt update && apt upgrade -y`

Not really nice, but mostly did the trick. I have some held back packages, due to dependcy problems, but nothing problematic.

Comment: If you're going to do this (the Debian way), you should at least run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, as simply running `sudo apt upgrade` will not perform a full upgrade as you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Check the basics first...

**Check your file system:**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Fix broken packages:**

Start `synaptic`. Select **Fix broken packages** from the Edit menu. Select this a few times, until no more errors appear.

**Software Updater:**

Run `Software Updater` before trying to perform the upgrade, and make sure that you're up to date.

**Note**: If these steps don't allow you to upgrade, please let me know the results of each step.

Comment: 1. I can't really see how a filesystem cause an update problem
2. There are not broken packages: ```root@pc-f-linux:~# dpkg -l | grep ^..r
root@pc-f-linux:~# 
```
3. The upgrade can't start without having the latest packages installed, so thats taken care of.

Comment: @Fabian So don't take my advice then :-(

Comment: please, explain then how the filesystem can be responsible for said error message?

Comment: @Fabian I'm not here to argue the merits of my recommendations. All three suggestions would take less time to try than to discuss them in detail. If you don't believe they may help, don't do them. In your earlier comment, you said *"no broken packages"*, yet you said *"the second half shows broken packages but also mentions "considering XXX as a solution"*. What is the XXX solution mentioned?

Comment: in the logfiles I have linked, all packages mentioned as broken in the second line also have in the next line for example (taken from line 1547): `Considering xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 10005 as a solution to xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 10005`

Ther are absoutely no broken packages when I run `dpgk -l` Would you like the whole output as well?

Comment: @Fabian In `synaptic`, in the Status tab, is there a section named "Pinned"?

Comment: it does not seem like it: https://imgur.com/a/cZ4Aigc

Comment: @Fabian Status please...

Comment: Still the same problem. I replied to your last question about the Status tab with a screenshot.

Comment: @Fabian I'm out of ideas. Sorry.